# Send a complex object over JSON and then rebuild it on another pc

Tags: c#, json

Can I use JSON to send a complex object from one pc to another?

From my understanding of JSON you can just stringy that object, then send the string to the other pc and then destringify it and rebuild the object again.

But now how does it know what object I have sent it? cause I could send it object A or object B ?

Is there a way to find out what object I have sent it? Or is part of JSON knowing what type of object you are going to receive?

Comment: It does not know. Sender and receiver should *somehow* agree on the type (you may inject some type info into the json for ex).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use JSON to send a complex object from one pc to another?

Yes

> But now how does it know what object I have sent it? cause I could
>   send it object A or object B ?

The receiver knows when it deserialises the Json. The receiver needs to know what the Json will look like or dynamically deserialise it if it cannot know. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object) on dynamically deserialising.

```
dynamic something = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If as client you use as an instance of a class like Spring RestTemplate, you can tell it which class it should expect the JSon to be an instance of, and convert it accordingly.

http://www.springframework.net/rest/doc-latest/reference/html/resttemplate.html

Answer (score 0):

> But now how does it know what object I have sent it? cause I could
>   send it object A or object B ?

The other side *should* be aware to the fact that a **JSON** object has been received in a **string** format and accordingly, to parse or deserialize it properly, just like in the following example, which takes a JSON string and *parse* it to JSON or C# object:

**In JavaScript:**

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

**In C#:**

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJsonString);
```

In addition, if it's an HTTP request, you can specify the content-type to: `application/json`.
This way, the receiver side could analyze it and understand it is a JSON string.

**Read more:**

- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

JSON **is** the string representation of data.

You either know what the other side expects or need to send additional meta-data.

Very often you know exactly what kind of object has been sent.

Adding additional meta-data could easily be done automatically (and I am sure there are a lot of libraries available):

```
{
  class: A
  entity: {...}
}
```